ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow (Failed to build pyarrow)
I am installing pyarrow on python 3.13:
pip install pyarrow

this is what I am getting:
C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313>py -3.13 -m pip install pyarrow
Collecting pyarrow
  Downloading pyarrow-17.0.0.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 1.1/1.1 MB 6.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting numpy>=1.16.6 (from pyarrow)
  Using cached numpy-2.1.2-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl.metadata (59 kB)
Using cached numpy-2.1.2-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl (12.6 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyarrow
  Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [346 lines of output]
      <string>:34: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\benchmarks
      copying benchmarks\array_ops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\benchmarks
      copying benchmarks\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\benchmarks
      copying benchmarks\convert_builtins.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\benchmarks
      copying benchmarks\convert_pandas.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\benchmarks
      copying benchmarks\io.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\benchmarks
      copying benchmarks\microbenchmarks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\benchmarks
      copying benchmarks\parquet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\benchmarks
      copying benchmarks\streaming.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\benchmarks
      copying benchmarks\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\benchmarks
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\acero.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\cffi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\compute.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\conftest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\csv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\cuda.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\dataset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\feather.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\pandas_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\substrait.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_compute_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_generated_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\scripts
      copying scripts\run_emscripten_tests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\scripts
      copying scripts\test_imports.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\scripts
      copying scripts\test_leak.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\scripts
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\examples\dataset
      copying examples\dataset\write_dataset_encrypted.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\examples\dataset
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\examples\flight
      copying examples\flight\client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\examples\flight
      copying examples\flight\middleware.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\examples\flight
      copying examples\flight\server.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\examples\flight
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\examples\parquet_encryption
      copying examples\parquet_encryption\sample_vault_kms_client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\examples\parquet_encryption
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\interchange
      copying pyarrow\interchange\buffer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\interchange
      copying pyarrow\interchange\column.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\interchange
      copying pyarrow\interchange\dataframe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\interchange
      copying pyarrow\interchange\from_dataframe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\interchange
      copying pyarrow\interchange\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\interchange
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\parquet
      copying pyarrow\parquet\core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-
      copying pyarrow\tests\arrow_39313.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\arrow_7980.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\pandas_examples.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\pandas_threaded_import.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\read_record_batch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\strategies.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_acero.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_adhoc_memory_leak.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_cffi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_compute.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_convert_builtin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-          copying pyarrow\tests\test_feather.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_flight.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_flight_async.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_fs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_gandiva.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_gdb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_io.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_json.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_jvm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_pandas.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_scalars.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_schema.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_sparse_tensor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_strategies.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_substrait.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_udf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\vendored
      copying pyarrow\vendored\docscrape.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\vendored
      copying pyarrow\vendored\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\vendored
      copying pyarrow\vendored\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\vendored
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\interchange
      copying pyarrow\tests\interchange\test_conversion.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\interchange
      copying pyarrow\tests\interchange\test_interchange_spec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\interchange
      copying pyarrow\tests\interchange\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\interchange
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\parquet\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\parquet\conftest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\parquet\encryption.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\parquet\test_basic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\parquet\test_compliant_nested_type.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\parquet\test_dataset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\parquet\test_data_types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\parquet\test_datetime.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\parquet\test_parquet_file.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\parquet\test_parquet_writer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\parquet\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      running egg_info
      writing pyarrow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pyarrow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to pyarrow.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to pyarrow.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'pyarrow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '..\LICENSE.txt'
      warning: no files found matching '..\NOTICE.txt'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '#*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.asv'
      writing manifest file 'pyarrow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\AWSSDKVariables.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\BuildUtils.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\DefineOptions.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\FindClangTools.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\FindGTestAlt.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-
      copying cmake_modules\FindProtobufAlt.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\FindPython3Alt.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\FindRapidJSONAlt.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\FindSQLite3Alt.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\FindgRPCAlt.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\Findlibrados.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\Findlz4Alt.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\FindorcAlt.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\GandivaAddBitcode.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\SetupCxxFlags.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\ThirdpartyToolchain.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\UseCython.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\Usevcpkg.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\aws_sdk_cpp_generate_variables.sh -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\san-config.cmake -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying cmake_modules\snappy.diff -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\cmake_modules
      copying pyarrow\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_acero.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_acero.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_azurefs.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_compute.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_compute.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_csv.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_csv.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_cuda.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_cuda.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_dataset.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_dataset.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_dataset_orc.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_dataset_parquet.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_dataset_parquet.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_dataset_parquet_encryption.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_dlpack.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_feather.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_flight.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_fs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_fs.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_gcsfs.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_hdfs.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_json.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_json.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_orc.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_orc.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_parquet.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_parquet.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_parquet_encryption.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_parquet_encryption.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_pyarrow_cpp_tests.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_pyarrow_cpp_tests.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_s3fs.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\_substrait.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\array.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\benchmark.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\builder.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\compat.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\config.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\device.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\error.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\gandiva.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\io.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\ipc.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\lib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\lib.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\memory.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\pandas-shim.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\public-api.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\scalar.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\table.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\tensor.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      copying pyarrow\types.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\common.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow_acero.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow_cuda.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow_dataset.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow_dataset_parquet.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow_feather.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow_flight.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow_fs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow_python.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow_substrait.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\libgandiva.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\libparquet_encryption.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\includes
      copying pyarrow\tests\bound_function_visit_strings.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\extensions.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\tests\pyarrow_cython_example.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\arrow_to_pandas.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\arrow_to_python_internal.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\async.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\benchmark.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\benchmark.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\common.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\common.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\csv.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\csv.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\datetime.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\datetime.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\decimal.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\decimal.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\deserialize.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\deserialize.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\extension_type.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\extension_type.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\filesystem.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\filesystem.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\flight.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\flight.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\gdb.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\gdb.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\helpers.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\helpers.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\inference.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\inference.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\init.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\init.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\ipc.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\ipc.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\iterators.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\numpy_convert.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\numpy_convert.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\numpy_internal.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\numpy_interop.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\numpy_to_arrow.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\numpy_to_arrow.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\parquet_encryption.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\parquet_encryption.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\pch.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\platform.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\pyarrow.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\pyarrow.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\pyarrow_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\pyarrow_lib.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\python_test.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\python_test.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\python_to_arrow.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\python_to_arrow.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\serialize.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\serialize.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\type_traits.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\udf.cc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\udf.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      copying pyarrow\src\arrow\python\visibility.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\src\arrow\python
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\feather
      copying pyarrow\tests\data\feather\v0.17.0.version.2-compression.lz4.feather -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\feather
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
      copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\README.md -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
      copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.emptyFile.jsn.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
      copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.emptyFile.orc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
      copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.test1.jsn.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-
      copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\decimal.jsn.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
      copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\decimal.orc -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.all-named-index.parquet -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.column-metadata-handling.parquet -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.parquet -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
      copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.some-named-index.parquet -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
      running build_ext
      creating C:\Users\navigatordev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zllpdq6m\pyarrow_7674497907ab40dbaa14d8f45104e542\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313
      -- Running cmake for PyArrow
      cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\navigatordev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zllpdq6m\pyarrow_7674497907ab40dbaa14d8f45104e542\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyarrow -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\python.exe -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\python.exe -DPYARROW_CXXFLAGS= -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_ARROW_CPP=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_CYTHON_CPP=off -DPYARROW_GENERATE_COVERAGE=off -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release C:\Users\navigatordev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zllpdq6m\pyarrow_7674497907ab40dbaa14d8f45104e542
      error: command 'cmake' failed: None
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pyarrow)


The latest version of pyarrow is 17.0.0.
Currently it is supported only till python 3.12.
You need work with python 3.12 until python 3.13 is supported.


PyArrow(v18.0.0.0) is currently compatible with Python 3.9, 3.10, 3.11, 3.12 and 3.13.
